# VBA excel paste as text

Tags: excel, vba, text, formatting, copy-paste

I need to paste numbers as text. It is problematic due to lots of zeros in front (but I need them there). First snippet, does not work (I found it on the internet).

```
Worksheets("B").Range("k7:k7").PasteSpecial Format:=”Text”, 
Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

The other I recorded, but it not always work.

```
PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Could someone suggest me a better solution, please?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `'` infront of your text in the cell? that should make excel treat your numbers as text and keep leading zeros

Comment: Or you can try to do as in this article, a couple of solutions: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US    Or try this formula:        ```=TEXT(A1,"000-00-0000")``` which will give this result:  **012-34-5678**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format the cells/column to 'Text' format then paste the numbers to preserve the leading zeros.  If it still doesn't work, try to paste the numbers to Notepad first and then copy all numbers in Notepad and paste it back to the cells/column now formatted as 'Text'.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy paste a single cell, instead of copy pasting get the value from the cell append single quote and store the value in the destination

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble recreating your issue.

I created a new sheet with with the following:
[image: Example spreadsheet]

The following code seems to do what you wish:

```
Sub pasteAsText()

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("C2").PasteSpecial

ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("C3").PasteSpecial

ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("C4").PasteSpecial


End Sub
```

Does that solve your problem?